# assign chart object to chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a programmatically created chart object and try to load it in chart control, but it get fail display nothing...

```
Chart Chart1 = GetMyChart(); //GetMyChart Return a chart object.
ChartControl1 = Chart1;
```

Comment: what you try ..explain more....

Comment: Would you mind giving us more code of it?

Comment: I create chart object in .cs file and function return chart objet to aspx.cs file any i try to show that object using chart control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found someting.... it works but I need to set each property of chart object to chartcontrol.

```
ChartArea[] ca = new ChartArea[1];
Chart1.ChartAreas.CopyTo(ca, 0);
ChartControl1.ChartAreas.Add(ca[0]);

Series[] s = new Series[5];
Chart1.Series.CopyTo(s, 0);
foreach (Series ss in s)
{
  if (ss != null)
  {
    ChartControl1.Series.Add(ss);
  }
}        
Legend[] l = new Legend[5];
Chart1.Legends.CopyTo(l, 0);
foreach (Legend ll in l)
{
  if (ll != null)
  {
    ChartControl1.Legends.Add(ll);
  }
}
```